# C++ getting console app in windows to print as fast as in linux

Tags: c++, printf, cout

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t b4 = time(NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    time_t a4 = time(NULL);
    std::cout << "Time taken is " << difftime(a4, b4);
    getchar();
}
```

in Windows when compiled/built/run with Visual Studio with commands:

```
CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /O2 /Oi /GL /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /FA /Fa"x64\Release\\" /Fo"x64\Release\\" /Fd"x64\Release\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:prompt ..\src\console_printf.cpp
         console_printf.cpp
       Link:
link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"Release\windows.exe" /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG:FULL /PDB:"Release\windows.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG:incremental /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"Release\windows.lib" /MACHINE:X64 x64\Release\console_printf.obj
```

finally prints (after printing `... 49998 49999`)

```
Time taken is 15
```

The same code when compiled/built/run on Linux with:

```
g++    -c -O2 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Release/GNU-Linux/_ext/511e4115/console_printf.o.d" -o build/Release/GNU-Linux/_ext/511e4115/console_printf.o ../src/console_printf.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Release/GNU-Linux
```

finally prints (after printing `... 49998 49999`)

```
Time taken is 1
```

That is, console/terminal printing in Linux is just much faster. Both tests were with optimizations turned on in release mode. Although tests were done on two separate machines (one running Windows/Visual Studio, the other running Linux), the computing powers of both are comparable.

Is there a way to get Windows console printing as fast as Linux? I run a numerically intensive/iterative code which periodically displays progress on the console and I am now worried that unnecessarily Windows console printing might be messing up with the recorded time for no fault of the algorithm but because Windows console printing is unwittingly the bottleneck.

Comment: Have you considered writing to a buffer and printing the buffer when it fills up? That way, IO will not be a limiting factor as much.

Comment: No idea why printing in Windows is so slow. It might be an issue with the console itself. You can try this first. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio

Comment: I haven't but that would seem to me to be something that the OS / compiler should take care of. Periodic logging to the console is useful but it defeats the purpose if it turns out to be the bottleneck when one is timing speed of different algorithms.

Comment: @AleksanderBobiński I tried to have  `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` but it makes no difference in the windows running time. There is no `printf` in my code. It is all just `cout`s.

Comment: How big are the console windows on both platforms? Scrolling all that text (as a graphic image) can take more time than the rest of the program.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The console window is the one that opens by default. A sample run (now it gives me 10 seconds) is at https://imgur.com/DChgBev

Comment: But I can set the size of the console window. It doesn't have to be 80x25. For example, I can have a 100x50 character display with a 3000 line buffer. That would take longer to scroll than an standard 80x25 window with a 25 line buffer.

Comment: You may be right, but it is quite annoying that the user has to hack the console size so as not to let `cout`s be the bottleneck on windows. Can the default console size be changed from within C++ code by any chance? Or is it a system-wide Windows setting?

Comment: Whats is the time if you use `\n` instead of `std::endl`?

Comment: There's a default somewhere, and there are various `SetConsole` functions in the Windows API. I typically handle periodic progress updates by throttling (only displaying the progress every half second or second) with a `'\r'` to overwrite the previous progress on the same line.

Comment: @AleksanderBobiński no change Sill displays 10 seconds as indicated in the image I linked to in the comments.

Comment: Are the numbers appearing as they are written (i.e. one at a time), in chunks of several numbers, or all at once?    From your commentary, it sounds like you want them to appear individually as they are written.

Comment: Also, you should write a test program that directly calls the Windows API function [`WriteConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) to see if it's your C++ library implementation causing the problem, rather than Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your standard library implementation may be part of your problem.   I ran the following code with plain vanilla Visual C++:

```
#define WRITE_CONSOLE_API
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>



int main() {
    LARGE_INTEGER freq;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    LARGE_INTEGER start;
    LARGE_INTEGER stop;
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(true);
#ifdef WRITE_CONSOLE_API
    char buf[20];
    static char buf2[2] = { '\r', '\0' };
    std::uninitialized_fill_n(buf, 20, '\0');
    auto con = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD l;
    DWORD lr;
#endif
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
#ifdef WRITE_CONSOLE_API
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
       if (i)
          WriteConsoleA(con, buf2, 1, &lr, NULL);
       _itoa(i, buf, 10);
       l = strlen(buf);
       WriteConsoleA(con, buf, l, &lr, NULL);
    }
    buf2[0] = '\n';
    WriteConsoleA(con, buf2, 1, &lr, NULL);
#else
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        std::cout << '\r' << i;
    std::cout << std::endl;
#endif
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
    double diff = stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart;
    std::cout << "Time taken is " << diff / freq.QuadPart << " secs\n";
    std::cin.ignore(1);
}
```

with `WRITE_CONSOLE_API` defined (where it used the Windows API call `WriteConsole`) and also with it not defined (where it used `std::cout`).

With `WRITE_CONSOLE_API` defined, the result was

```
Time taken is 2.12448 secs
```

With `WRITE_CONSOLE_API` not defined, the result was

```
Time taken is 6.25676 secs
```

if you use a space instead of `\r` (i.e. to force the console window to scroll), you get

```
Time taken is 3.02435 secs
```

with `WRITE_CONSOLE_API` defined, and

```
Time taken is 7.27557 secs
```

with `WRITE_CONSOLE_API` not defined.  Scrolling appears to consistently add 1 second to both times.

You should try this on your own machine, because the timings may vary.

I had debugging on, so NO optimization.  With optimization, the standard library version was reduced to 6.8 seconds (Scrolling) and 5.6 seconds (nonscrolling), but the Windows API version didn't change.

If you truly want to separate the program's actual work from the vagaries of the operating system, you could create a thread to do the work, and use the other thread to write progress to the console. You really only need to connect them with the actual progress count, as a `std::atomic<`*`some_int_type`*`>`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to improve console I/O (which is the bottleneck for most I/O bound applications) print to a buffer then block write the buffer to a console.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main ()
{
    std::string buffer;
    buffer.reserve(5000);
    std::ostringstream number_stream(buffer);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i)
    {
        number_stream << i << " ";
    }
    number_stream << "\n";
    const unsigned int length = buffer.length();
    std::cout.write(buffer.c_str(), length);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code uses a `std::string` for its buffer.  All the numbers are formatted (human readable) into the buffer.  The buffer is then written to the console using a block write.

The idea behind `buffer.reserve()` is to allocate a large enough buffer to reduce the reallocations.

Comment: I think OP wants the numbers to appear in the console as they are written, not just in one big chunk at the end.

Comment: The OP is writing one number at a time to the console.  This is slow.  The code I presented writes one number at a time to a buffer, then writes the buffer to the console.  This is a lot faster because the formatting step writes to a buffer and the block write has the least amount of overhead when writing to a stream or the console.  Otherwise, the OP is at the mercy of the operating system.

Comment: Yes, well the code OP posted is thwarting the desired result as stated in the last paragraph of the question.  Plus, there's no evidence yet that the bottleneck is in the operating system, as opposed to the library implementation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Do you know if Linux, behind the scenes, does just this automatically?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This code does not print on the console at all. See godbolt link https://godbolt.org/z/7vaPbPxPf